# Set Kd too high

Tags: control

In a control system, why when I set Kd (differentiate) too high then it has a buzzling sound? Is it because of the system is moving up and down very fast?

Comment: What is your system?

Comment: A simple (Kp, Kd, Ki) system controlling a rotating disk. There is an pendulum attached to the disk.

Comment: Users would probably like a bit more information about you have things connected and the control working to be able to clearly tell you the source of such a symptom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sort of vibration is common when the D term gain is too high.  This is because it amplifies whatever noise is on the error signal.  If the system can't respond as fast as the noise, then you could get a buzzing sound from the motor.

Comment: I have see it on a few of your recent posts, please do not talk about the question's validity in your answer. If you want to leave feedback on how to edit it, leave a constructive comment, if you want a discussion of what is wrong in detail, go to meta, not in your question. This seems to be a basic question and you have almost answered it here, maybe explain in a bit more detail would be nice, but this already seems to deserve an upvote.

Comment: @Kortuk: I was trying to explain why I was being brief.  I think the question is very vague and will rightfully be closed as a result, so putting much effort into a question is kindof pointless.  Besides, what's wrong with talking about the question in a answer?  It seems legitimate to me in some cases.  Where is the rule that says this is not allowed or even discourage?

Comment: Sorry, I have not had to dig up the rule in forever. I can look a bit later, for now I can tell you the reasoning. The answer field is for answers to the question, not for meta discussion, that is what meta is for. I feel the reason that you kept your answer vague and simple is pretty obvious when looking at the question, although I wish your answer was more detailed. Sorry to leave you without a link at the moment, but cease and desist discussing the quality of the question in place where you should be discussing a solution.